# Finding difference between rating index using Excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I'm pretty new to Excel formulas. I have two sheets in excel and I need to add two calculated columns to compute a rating difference. How can I achieve this using Excel formulas?

**RatingsSheet**

```
RaterA  RaterB  value
 Aaa     AAA      1
 Aa1     AA+      2
 Aa2     AA       3
 Aa3     AA-      4
```

I have another sheet where I have to compute the difference in value that should go into last two columns RateAdiff(PrevRatingA-CurrRatingA) and RateBdiff(PrevRatingB-CurrRatingB)

**Analysis Sheet**

```
Entity  PrevRatingA  CurrRatingA  PrevRatingB CurrRatingB RateAdiff RateBdiff
1234       Aaa         Aa3           AA-         AA+         -3        2
4355       Aa2         Aa2           AA+         AA           0       -1
```

Comment: You want VLOOKUP to return the value.  So you will need two VLOOKUPs, one subtracted from the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this through multiple options:

Formula in Analysis Sheet cell `F2`:

```
=SUMIF(RatingSheet!A:A,B2,RatingSheet!C:C)-SUMIF(RatingSheet!A:A,C2,RatingSheet!C:C)
```

Formula in Analysis Sheet cell `G2`:

```
=SUMIF(RatingSheet!B:B,D2,RatingSheet!C:C)-SUMIF(RatingSheet!B:B,E2,RatingSheet!C:C)
```

You could also use a combo of `INDEX` and `MATCH`:

`F2`:

```
=INDEX(RatingSheet!C:C,MATCH(B2,RatingSheet!A:A,0))-INDEX(RatingSheet!C:C,MATCH(C2,RatingSheet!A:A,0))
```

`G2`:

```
=INDEX(RatingSheet!C:C,MATCH(D2,RatingSheet!B:B,0))-INDEX(RatingSheet!C:C,MATCH(E2,RatingSheet!B:B,0))
```

Another possibility would be looking `VLOOKUP` but at its least `INDEX & MATCH` is just as fast in processing, and at best it's significantly faster. If you new to formulas I would recommend to remember that combo of formulas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLOOKUP() formula as follows. For cell RateAdiff (`F9`):

```
=VLOOKUP(B9,$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(C9,$A$2:$C$5,3,FALSE)
```

For cell RateBdiff(`G9`):

```
=VLOOKUP(D9,$B$2:$C$5,2,FALSE)-VLOOKUP(E9,$B$2:$C$5,2,FALSE)
```

Once you have the 2 formulas in the first row (Entity 1234) you can drag them down. See data for this example:

[image]

Comment: @JvdV: Thanks for the heads-up, I just corrected. It's weird, I'd thought you always calculate difference as `Diff = Current - Previous`

Comment: @JvdV : Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: Thanks a ton Kaiser!